Calculate the height of body from the header and footer heights
I have a header with height: 8rem;
.header {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 8rem;
}

Then I have a footer with height: 5rem;
footer
{
    width:100%; 
    height: 5rem;    
}

I'm trying to calculate the height of the body-content to fit 100% the height of the screen. What I came up with is
.body-content{
  height: calc(100vh - 8rem - 5rem);
}

However this is not working and the height is longer than the screen. On trial and error, what's working perfect is:
.body-content{
  height: calc(100vh - 15.5rem);
}

But shouldn't it be 100% the height of the screen - height of the header - height of footer?

I'm trying to calculate the height of the body-content to fit 100% the height of the screen I would say you arent doing that, otherwise 100vh should be enough?

Could you provide your other CSS and HTML

@Wimanicesir if I do that it'll be longer than the screen and I'd have to scroll. The header is 8rem and footer is 5rem so the body in the middle should be 100% minus 13rem. Or am i wrong here?

Add html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0 } and see if that helps.

Nobody can tell what's going wrong with your layout using information you shared, but it looks like you are trying to build a web page with a top header with height = 8rem, a bottom footer with height 5rem and a content between those elements that is tall as much to fill all remaining space in viewport.
I'd like to suggest you a different approach, using css display: flex property.
Run the following snippet:


html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  /* this does the magic */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  /* fixed height, no shrink */
  height: 8rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  /* fixed height, no shrink */
  height: 5rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
}

.body-content {
  /* variable height, scroll content if needed */
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  
  background: #e5e5e5;
  margin: 0;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flex Layout Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <main class="body-content">Content</main>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</body>



Flexbox is the modern way to design layouts, you can learn all you need visiting the following page: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
